# Tuning spacing between words

Tags: spacing

At the moment it seems that TeX enlarges spacing between paragraphs (and sometimes words) in order to fit the page. Is there any way to prevent this? The example where the problem can be seen (sorry it's not in English) is below. The left column seems fine while in the right one the problem occurs.[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the instruction `\raggedbottom` to the preamble?

Comment: @mico nope that seems to be just the thing, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `\raggedbottom` instruction in your preamble (thanks @Mico for the solution)